# Trying to use variable as where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I might have a date to search on and I might not.  I have a variable that creates a where clause: where field1 = date, if there is a date otherwise i create a blank varable.  the problem is adding this to the end of my sql statement.

```
Select * from table + @where 
Select @ from table & @where
```

neither work

> msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'

Comment: Hint : Use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Dynamic SQL is a big topic, but if you're using it for a dynamic search condition specifically, there's more to consider. Sometimes you absolutely need it, sometimes you don't; sometimes it makes sense to build the query on the server side, sometimes it makes more sense to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be a procedure with code that allows having a NULL argument. Dynamic SQL can get injected if done poorly or become hard to maintain if you have conditional branches to add more joins, clauses in the WHERE, etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_proc 
@search_date DATETIME

AS

BEGIN 

SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE your_date_col >= ISNULL(@search_date, '9999-12-31')
END
GO
```

Now, if you have a variable, you can call your procedure with it:

```
DECLARE @variable DATETIME = '2018-01-01'
EXEC your_proc @variable
```

Or, you can leave it NULL and run the same code:

```
EXEC your_proc NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the where clause so it will only use the variable when it is not empty,
like this for example

```
declare @SearchValue date = null -- set a date here if you want to use this variable in the where clause

select t.* 
from   YourTable t
where  (@SearchValue is null or t.YourDateColumn = @SearchValue)
```

when the variable `@SearchValue` is empty, then there will be no check done because the expression between the brackets will already be `true`

Like this you can avoid using dynamic sql

Comment: That's a bad idea. [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) end up generating bad execution plans. The solution is to either use dynamic SQL, use `WITH RECOMPILE` or *not* use redundant parameters in the first place